# how create msdeploy package without absolute path in content folder?

Tags: azure, msdeploy

I have a problem related to creating msdeploy package for deploying to azure web app.
I run `msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<SiteName>" -dest:package=test.zip` And after investigating package i found that it contains a full hierarchy of folders eg: `\Content\C_C\inetpub\wwwroot\<SiteName>\` and when i am trying to deploy this package to azure a have an exception because i don't have such permissions.
Question: how to remove path from content folder so my archive will looks like `\Content\<SiteName>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of investigation i figure out how to do this:

`$msDeployPackageCommand = "$MsDeployExePath
 -source:iisApp=$PathToApplication
 -dest:package=$ZipCreationPath
 -verb:sync
 -enableLink:contentLibExtension
 -replace:match=$ReplacePathToApplication,replace=$replaceWith
 -retryAttempts:2
 -disablerule:BackupRule
 -declareParam:name='PackageManagementService',kind='ProviderPath',scope='IisApp',match=$ReplacePathToApplication,defaultValue=$replaceWith";`

This works fine.